# Fllutter: why keyboard's text type doesn't change on numeric keyboard on iOS?

Tags: flutter

```
on android that works, but on iOS doesn't shown numeric keyboard
```

I used:
code:
-keyboardType: TextInputType.number,

```
 - keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true, signed: true),

 -inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[ 
FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly 
]
but nothing works

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekeHw.png
```

Comment: Please add your other file code where this text field is used!

Comment: I use this textfield only in this file. Or do you need complete code?

Comment: try this ```keyboardType: TextInputType.number```